# How to get the HTML of a website with Python as we get via inspect option in chrome

Tags: python, html, web-crawler

I would like to get the html of the website with a python script such that I can crawl all the links and visit those that contain the files I want to download.

The problem I have is that when I use the requests library I get the code without rendered JS. But even when I tried an approach with selenium I got the unrendered html.
Does somebody know how I could achieve getting just the html that I can see when I click 'Inspect' in Google Chrome or 'Element-Information' in Safari?

Thank you a lot for your help!

Cheers

Niklas

Comment: Don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]. Don't link to your code, include it here in the question, as formatted text, as a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# URL of the page to scrape
url = 'https://public.tableau.com/app/discover/business-dashboards'

driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)  # Adjust the sleep time if necessary

# Find elements - adjust the selectors based on actual page structure
dashboard_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a.link')

dashboards = []
for element in dashboard_elements:
    title = element.text
    link = element.get_attribute('href')
    dashboards.append({'title': title, 'link': link})

driver.quit()

for dashboard in dashboards:
    print(f"Title: {dashboard['title']}, Link: {dashboard['link']}")
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your contribution @Harish. Does this work for you? Because when I execute the code, dashboards is still empty and nothing is printed.